# PHP include_once fails without warning or error for an existing file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, require-once

Got me an error thats got me stumped. Am trying to implement a custom class loader in php. Am on version 5.6.11. The problem is that I am building up the path to a file dynamically and then doing an "include_once" on that path. PHP is just terminating execution at that point with no warnings or error messages. The path is valid. The code is basically like this

```
require_once "lib/includes/web/classloader/default.php";
require_once "lib/includes/web/controller/default.php";
$classloader = new web\classloaders\ClassLoader();
$controller_path = $classloader->registerController();
if($controller_path != null){
    require_once("$controller_path");
}
```

The file_exists and is_readable checks are done in the registerController() function of the class loader.

I have also tried this:

```
require_once $controller_path;
```

and this:

```
require_once($controller_path);
```

Any ideas?

regards

Comment: require_once (dirname(__FILE__)  . '/default.php');

Comment: I am using xampp on windows 10

Comment: I'm new with the namespace, but it'snt cause your $classloader is in an other namespace ? And do you have check if your file name have uppercase, kind default.php -> Default.php ?

Comment: Do Linux-like paths work in windows?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the apache log, not just what may appear on screen?

Comment: Also, how have you verified which line of code is failing? Have you done the old `var_dump`/`die()` debugging on each line?

Comment: thanks for those speedy responses. Looks like I have issues with namespacing. Let me try and walk through those. will let you know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the syntax as I tested with the code. The problem should be on the path. Try using `echo $controller_path; die();` before using require_once to see the path.

OR

You can insert

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

at the beginning of the PHP page to **enable error display** so that you can see what is causing the error..

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The error was in the namespaces used. I managed to trace the source of the problem to one of the classes which i had not correctly namespaced. Xenofexs post your hint and i will accept it.